# How to edit the video frames from AVCapture

Tags: ios

I want to stream a video to a local server continuously. For that I want to capture the frames of video and also want to edit the frame to embed another watermark image background and make it as movie with audio and stream to server. Can anyone help me out as how to achieve this task using AVFoundation in iOS?